# interface with codes or exceptions returned by method

Tags: c#, interface

I am designing an interface to transfer files and manipulate them on some remote server.
The confusion is, whether methods on the interface should return codes for callers ? benefit assumed is that caller would not have to catch exceptions.

Or the right way to go about is return voids and throw exceptions on failure conditions ??? if so should the exceptions be custom ? or the primitive ones defined by language (C# in this case) ??

```
 //Remote transfer interface 1
 enum codes { SUCCESS, FAIL, HOSTUNREACHABLE, so-on and so forth }
 codes init(String host, int port);
 codes transferFile(String filepath, String remotename);
 codes deleteRemote(String remotePath);
```

The second type of iterface to transfer

```
 //Remote transfer interface 2
 //Following methods throw exceptions when they occur, catched by caller..
 void init(String host, int port);
 void transferFile(String filepath, String remotename);
 void deleteRemote(String remotePath);
```

Can you guys tell which way is best and why ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no best solution in absolute here. All depends on your API design. 
If you want to create compact, or "self contained" API, can think about handling IO exception *inside* implementation of that interface.

Consider a fact that there will be exception that you're not going to handle inside, and would like that *caller* handles them in some way.

This type of implementation is good about as it hides deep details of how actually all "stuff" works, and "talks" with the caller via standardized codes.

Example: you're writing a communication layer for `talking-ring` on PLC controllers, with some custom proprietary protocol. The caller may avoid  care about *how* protocol works (so handle expected and unexpected possible exception that may occur during program run), but just call functions and get information back about fact, either it succeed, or failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the API on CLR then all languages using the API are able to handle Exceptions and you should use them.

Exceptions enfore error handling, checking for a return code can be forgotten easily and when an error occures the problem might show way later in the code. And you might have no way to get to know what whent wrong without debuging and restore exactly the same preconditions like when the error occured.
With Exceptions you get the exact error information incase you forgot to handle some error case and you enforce to handle the error when it happens and not later in the program flow-.